# Allow own signed certificat in owncloud on a synology

Tags: certificate, owncloud, synology, onlyoffice

I have owncloud version 9.1.8 running on a synology. Now I installed onlyoffice on a local server with a self signed certificat. It is important to know, that the onlyoffice server is running locally in a network. So I cannot access the server like e.g. with lets encrypt, because I only have a local server name and not a public server name. Lets Encrypt therefore cannot verify the server. However if I want (and if you have a solution doing that), I can access the internet using the server.
Now i have the problem, that owncloud delivers me the following error message

> "Error while downloading the document file to be converted."

when I want to save the url in the onlyoffice configuration in owncloud. I guess the problem is, that I am using a self signed certificat. Do you know what I can do? Google does not really help me.

Answer (score 0):

> "Error while downloading the document file to be converted."

means that DocumentServer cannot validate your storage's self-signed certificate (OC in your case)
There are 2 possible workarounds:
1) Change  `"rejectUnauthorized"` to `false` in the /etc/onlyoffice/documentserver/default.json config file

2) Change the default [Node.js CAstore](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_use_openssl_ca_use_bundled_ca):

Edit the files:
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/onlyoffice-documentserver-converter.conf
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/onlyoffice-documentserver-docservice.conf

Add a flag `--use-openssl-ca` to the parameters in [this line](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/document-server-package/blob/master/common/documentserver/supervisor/onlyoffice-documentserver-converter.conf#L2)

Then you need to add your certificate to the the default CA store and restart ONLYOFFICE services:

```
supervisorctl restart all
```